# fm as android application in eclipse

Tags: android

I have got an error in the line below.

```
aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

the error says that the static field `Context.AUDIO_SERVICE` should be accessed in a static way.
What is the solution?

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Access it in a static way. The answer is there in your question itself :

```
aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```